# How can I make some messages appear in Gmail but not in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

Yes snooping is bad. But sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.

My bf has a Gmail acct. He uses Outlook for it. Going back thru history on Google Chrome I noticed that he used Gmail via internet and some of the emails contained pics, subject lines of hey babe and other various similarities that raised a red flag.

When I open outlook, there are no traces of the emails. When I click on the individual ones under history it takes me to the login for gmail and not outlook.

My question: If the history for that shows the same gmail address associated with Outlook, is there a setting that can be set within gmail.com that will only send certain emails to outlook yet not some others, which can only be accessed by signing into gmail.com?

Comment: Are the outlook settings for the gmail account on IMAP or POP3? If they're on POP3, Outlook doesn't sync all messages from gmail

Comment: Outlook also uses the Internet. In case of Chrome, say web.

Comment: BTW, I doubt you can check email subject line, images and Gmail address just by looking at history of Chrome. The question doesn't look legit to me.

Comment: It's going to be better to just approach your boyfriend regarding this instead of trying to go behind his back.

Answer (score 3):

You can create various labels and filters in gmail. You can set Outlook to download only specific messages. Also, when you click on the 'All Email' link in gmail, it will show all hidden and archived messages.